# (Mis)understanding Seq.cache

Tags: f#, sequence

I have the following code (inside a larger function, but that shouldn't matter):

```
let ordersForTask = Dictionary<_, _>()

let getOrdersForTask task =
    match ordersForTask.TryGetValue task with
    | true, orders -> orders
    | false, _ ->
        let orders =
            scenario.Orders
            |> Seq.filter (fun (order : Order) -> order.Tasks.Contains(task))
            |> Seq.cache

        ordersForTask.Add(task, orders)
        orders
```

From what I understand, that should lead to `order.Tasks.Contains()` being called exactly once for each pair of `order` and `task` values, no matter how often `getOrdersForTask` is called with the same `task` value, because the input sequence is only iterated (at most) once. However, that does not appear to be the case; if I call the function `n` times for all the values of `task` that I have, profiling shows `n *  number of orders * number of tasks` calls to `Contains()`.

Replacing `Seq.cache` with `Seq.toList` has the effect I expected, but I want to avoid incurring the cost for `Seq.toList`.

What am I misunderstanding about `Seq.cache` or doing wrong in its usage?

Comment: Looks like your function returns a new cached sequence every time you invoke the function. Maybe this will be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1060594/3330348

Comment: `task` is of a normal CLR class defined somewhere in upstream C# code.

Comment: Does it override Equals and/or GetHashCode?

Comment: Yes, it implements `IEquatable<T>`. (And as I mentioned, the number of calls is what I expect when using `Seq.toList`, so hashing appears to work. :-))

Comment: just to make sure I tried your construct with `Task = int`, `orders = int seq` and a simple function (`n -> n % 5 == 0`) for the filtering (including trace-messages to see calls) - well in F# interactive it works as it should (meaning: the filter function will only be called the first time I evaluate with a certain number) - can you try to give a minimal example showing your problem, so we can have a *failing* version to look at?

Comment: FYI; it could be useful to study [Seq.cache](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/fsharp4/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs) (row 1385). Note that there's a cost of using Seq.cache as well (most notably the locks). Sometimes Seq.toArray can be more efficient.

Comment: Agree with @CarstenKönig if you could provide a self-contained example it would be much easier to investigate

Comment: Here's a self-contained repro attempt, along the lines of @CarstenKönig's comment.  Works fine.  We are going to need complete sample code. https://gist.github.com/latkin/1fa448d941c9383a4bc7